# XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref when read inputStream

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I got an exception with parser xml file, I have searched some questions with same exception but I still did not find the solution:

I'm trying to ignore below code in xml file by using `XmlPullParser`:

**1. Xml code**

```
<script type="text/template" class="sidebarTemplate">
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li class="sidebarDate">1 hour ago</li>
                <!--
                <li class="sidebarTags"><a href="http://xkcn.info/tagged/girl-xinh" class="sidebarTag">#girl xinh </a><a href="http://xkcn.info/tagged/pretty-girl" class="sidebarTag">#pretty girl </a><a href="http://xkcn.info/tagged/vietnam-girl" class="sidebarTag">#vietnam girl </a><a href="http://xkcn.info/tagged/beautiful-girl-photo" class="sidebarTag">#beautiful girl photo </a><a href="http://xkcn.info/tagged/photography" class="sidebarTag">#photography </a></span></li>
                -->
                <li class="sidebarShare">
                    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://xkcn.info/post/125394864133/kieu-nga-by-thích-việt-hoàng-a-lot-more-at&amp;width&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=65&amp;width=55&amp;appId=352683068141771" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:65px;width:55px" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
                    <!--<ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.tumblr.com/reblog/125394864133/CzhuMx8H" class="reblog_button"style="display: block;width:25px;height:25px;"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 21 21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="#ccc"><path d="M5.01092527,5.99908429 L16.0088498,5.99908429 L16.136,9.508 L20.836,4.752 L16.136,0.083 L16.1360004,3.01110845 L2.09985349,3.01110845 C1.50585349,3.01110845 0.979248041,3.44726568 0.979248041,4.45007306 L0.979248041,10.9999998 L3.98376463,8.30993634 L3.98376463,6.89801007 C3.98376463,6.20867902 4.71892527,5.99908429 5.01092527,5.99908429 Z"></path><path d="M17.1420002,13.2800293 C17.1420002,13.5720293 17.022957,14.0490723 16.730957,14.0490723 L4.92919922,14.0490723 L4.92919922,11 L0.5,15.806 L4.92919922,20.5103758 L5.00469971,16.9990234 L18.9700928,16.9990234 C19.5640928,16.9990234 19.9453125,16.4010001 19.9453125,15.8060001 L19.9453125,9.5324707 L17.142,12.203"></path></svg></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fxkcn.info%2Fpost%2F125394864133%2Fkieu-nga-by-th%C3%ADch-vi%E1%BB%87t-ho%C3%A0ng-a-lot-more-at" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=http%3A%2F%2Fxkcn.info%2Fpost%2F125394864133%2Fkieu-nga-by-th%C3%ADch-vi%E1%BB%87t-ho%C3%A0ng-a-lot-more-at" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>-->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </script>
```

**2. Parser code**

```
private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Exception log**

```
XMLPullParserException org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:START_TAG <iframe src='sidebarShare'>@80:174 in java.io.InputStreamReader@5288e374)
```

I had made some `debug` and see that when `parser` call next (which I want it points to `iframe` tag --> `exception` occurs)
Any body can help or give me a suggestion ? 
Thanks!

Comment: I just parsed it successfully with the 'xmllint' utility, and I don't see an error while reading by hand. I would try parsing it with some other XML tools, to see whether it's a problem in the document, or perhaps in xmlpullparser. Also, try removing the "src" attribute, and see if that narrows down the problem.